# Remove the micro seconds from model method datetime objects

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

I have this method, it returns the time_left hence the name.

My problem is the additional microseconds appended at the end.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class ModelClass(models.Model):
    ....
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()    

    @property
        def time_left(self):
            data = {"in_negative": False}
            remaining = self.due_date - now()
            data["remaining"] = remaining
            if remaining.days < 0:
                data["in_negative"] = True
            return data
```

This is what I get on my template

`3 days, 10:38:53.070894`

What I want

`3 days, 10:38:53`

Answer (score 0):

I you are interested only getting the strings you could strip the seconds from the period `.` and ignore the right side of the string. Example:

```
@property
def time_left(self):
    data = { 'in_negative':False }
    remaining = self.due_date - now()
    if remaining.days < 0:
        data['in_negative'] = True
    date_str = str(remaining).split(".")[0]
    data["remaining"] = date_str
    return data
```

Comment: This feels a little dirty :| is there a native python/django way to do this? maybe in the template?